# Should we always use @NotNull or @Nullable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, nullable, notnull

Should we always use `@NotNull` or `@Nullable` in method parameters even if it appears to be obvious?

```
@NotNull
public static int add(@NotNull int a, @NotNull int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

To clarify:

Now I know that one can't pass `null` to primitive variable but I wanted to ask what if I would have a method (with non-primitive parameters) to which `null` can be passed but from the name of the method it would be obvious that you can't pass null because for example, you can't add something to `null`?

```
@NotNull
public static Integer add(@NotNull Integer a, @NotNull Integer b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: @PeterRader This question is OK, me also have the same question with Intellij

Comment: Intellij will complain if you use these annotation on primitives or `void`.  I suggest focusing on problems which can happen, rather than trying to solve problems which cannot.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should edit the question or leave it as it is but I wanted to ask what if I would have a method to which null can be passed (non-primitive) but from the name of the method it would be obvious that you can't pass null because you can't add something to null? - something like that

Comment: @Defozo I wouldn't rely on the name of the method too much. You might have `null` to act like `Double.NaN` so it might be allowed.

Comment: I would add an EDIT to the question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: For your edit, those integers could come from anywhere. Although it's obvious you're adding two integers and they *shouldn't* be null, it doesn't mean they aren't unless you checked beforehand.

Comment: The question was nonsense before and after clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java primitive types such as `int` can never be `null`, this is enforced by the compiler, so the annotations in your code are completely unnecessary.

Even if you managed to pass an `Integer` as a parameter (via auto-unboxing), a `null` value won't be allowed in most cases:

```
add(1, (Integer) null);
=> Null pointer access: This expression of type Integer is null but requires auto-unboxing.
```

But if a null *does* manage to be passed as an argument (say, if one of the arguments is a `null` attribute), *the annotations won't prevent it*, causing a runtime `NullPointerException`. If you're so concerned about passing `null` values (which you shouldn't), you can use [`Optional`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) to gracefully handle the case when one of the arguments is `null`:

```
public static Optional<Integer> add(Integer a, Integer b) {
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return Optional.empty();
    return Optional.of(a + b);
}
```

Now it'll be the caller's responsibility to determine what to do if the value couldn't be computed, with the added benefit that the caller now is aware that this could happen.

Comment: What if there is an Integer?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez your update does not fit every situation: `Integer a=null; add(i,a);` adds a `null`.

Comment: No, I mean if I would have `public static Integer add(@NotNull Integer a, @NotNull Integer b)`?

Comment: @PeterRader did you test it? because in fact, it _does_ cover that situation.

Comment: @Defozo that's a different situation, an `Integer` _can_ be `null`, in that case using the annotations would be justified, although a bit paranoid.

Comment: So should I be paranoid and keep adding @NotNull or nobody cares?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Make `a` as an public field and it is allowed.

Comment: @Defozo even adding it won't protect you from certain edge cases, as the one mentioned by Peter. You _will_ get a runtime null pointer exception, annotation or no annotation. I don't think over-using those annotations is a good idea. If protecting from nulls is so important to you, consider using `Optional` instead.

Comment: @Defozo I further expanded my answer.

Comment: I guess Optional is the future and there's no place for null, isn't that right?

Comment: No, `Optional` is not a replacement for `null`. Read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html). Quoting: "It is important to note that the intention of the Optional class is not to replace every single null reference. Instead, its purpose is to help design more-comprehensible APIs so that by just reading the signature of a method, you can tell whether you can expect an optional value"

Answer (score 1):

> what if I would have a method to which null can be passed (non-primitive) but from the name of the method it would be obvious that you can't pass null because you can't add something to null?

You can't rely on the name. Consider

```
Integer add(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a == null|| b == null ? null : a + b;
}
```

You might say, a method like this won't handle `null` but there are such methods.

From `java.util.Objects`

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

and

```
public static boolean deepEquals(Object a, Object b) {
    if (a == b)
        return true;
    else if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;
    else
        return Arrays.deepEquals0(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally its important to the implementation to have a `null`-value or not.

But in a sitouation where you have **no implementation** (or have non yet) like a API, they must be used in the entire API in combination with the documentation (javadoc i.e.).

By the way, your first question was bad because `int` can not hold null. After your clarification the question makes no sense anymore.